# TypeScript: Conditional method availability based on generic type state

Tags: typescript

I'm working with TypeScript and have a base class, `BaseClass`, which uses a generic type `IsManual` to toggle its behavior. The class has a method `manually()` to update the `_isManually` state variable. Another method, `callRequest()`, changes its behavior based on this `_isManually` state.

Here's the relevant code:

```
type ManualValue = true | false;

export class Request {
    request() {
        return fetch('SOME_ROUTE');
    }

    foo() {
        return 1;
    }
}

export default class BaseClass<IsManual extends ManualValue = false> {
    _isManually: IsManual = false as IsManual;

    manually(): Omit<this, keyof BaseClass<any>> & BaseClass<true>;
    manually(value: true): Omit<this, keyof BaseClass<any>> & BaseClass<true>;
    manually(value: false): Omit<this, keyof BaseClass<any>> & BaseClass<false>;
    manually(value?: ManualValue): BaseClass<ManualValue> {
        if (value === undefined) {
            this._isManually = true as IsManual;
        } else {
            this._isManually = value as IsManual;
        }
        return this as BaseClass<IsManual>;
    } 
}

export class TestBaseClass extends BaseClass {
    callRequest(payload?: any) {
        const request = new Request();

        if (this._isManually) {
            return request;
        }

        return request.request();
    }
}

const t = new TestBaseClass();

t.manually().callRequest();
```

I expect that after calling `t.manually().callRequest()`, TypeScript would dynamically adjust method availability based on the value of `_isManually`. Specifically, I want to access methods from either the `Request` class or its `request()` method depending on the `_isManually` flag.

However, this is not happening as expected. How can I make TypeScript recognize the methods conditionally?

You can experiment with the code in this [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgOwK5wDYDU1OgXisAJ2ygB8oAzNAZwgG4AoeiADzAHsDgoBjVOKqlABKEAI7YqXAN70ocqATETgACgCUUGfO0KIwJAQQU93ABYqA5AGUA8jACiAfSE2AqgBV7FtQ20BfRm1yNjZ1TVkdOUV9QygARl95AICmVg4uABMISiRULl5+QQAhfggAYT4BAB4ASSp4ZDQoFmAIBAzBBpQMLFwKaggAPnDtRwBLesRu1BAALig6rqa8SlQaKH4FycbUBgi5AFsptBn1eZsDseAq4FMJgBooAGsIEDZyKBKaCsKqxBBBsMAGSfUo-aqEbCDRKHY6oU4AN1680hEDU50u11uD2er3eoO+lSofwQAOBBPKRJuRCGMKgRx2iOR-TWaIxVxudyojxebw+X0pv3+gKgIIF4OJqxo0P29LhTNQ2AA-PMlj1FWyKRKqmrMBrhlpIlAxh8VEiNVAcFaoEh2tkxggIBkNIajfJsVQAHTjbbTECW-A0jaCRZwun+ZqskZu91c70TNUzAPm4ibUM7cNJWXaaIGIwe4Naqnp7oyiP0FIsdicHhEqDuCCScV1lptDpFwrRuTcE4icSN1RgOAgVBsOAZFUbUku7PybhsBCSXT9pd4R0Ad2ESgH6j2bpNUBUHvjvpOIBnMfkudiihXwEzchSbuvRlvyk9b53PllyUY88XXBcGuECbg2TZgkSu6MMAnoMn66iej28J9sou5AA)

##### Further Attempts:

When I tried to chain the methods like this:

```
t.manually().callRequest().request();
```

I received a TypeScript error:

```
Property 'request' does not exist on type 'Request | Promise<Response>'.
```

This contradicts my expectations based on the `_isManually` flag, as I expected TypeScript to recognize that `callRequest()` would return an instance of the `Request` class and allow me to call its `request()` method.

I also attempted to use TypeScript's conditional types in the `callRequest()` method to directly depend on the `_isManually` property, like so:

```
export class TestBaseClass extends BaseClass {
    callRequest(payload?: any): this['_isManually'] extends true ? Request : Promise<Response> {
        const request = new Request();

        if (this._isManually) {
            return request as any;
        }

        return request.request() as any;
    }
}
```

I hoped that by doing this, the TypeScript compiler would understand the conditional return types and adjust the method suggestions accordingly.

Outcome:
Regardless of whether I called the `manually()` method or not, TypeScript did not adjust the available methods based on the `_isManually` flag. The issue remained unchanged: TypeScript did not recognize the methods I expected to be available.

**UPDATE:**
This question is a rephrasing of a question I asked earlier, to make it clearer I've created new one, the above code has been improved with the help of @jcalz.

Comment: So you're trying to get TypeScript to change the *shape* of the object based on whether you've called `manually`?

Comment: yes I wanted to define return type based on `_isManually` flag, so to return entire class or `request()` response

Comment: FWIW, if you get this working, I wouldn't mutate the instance like that. The type of the instance won't change (just the type of the return value of `manually`). So `const b = new BaseClass<false>();` followed by `b.manually();` means `b` now has a type that's out of sync with its implementation. Instead, return a *new* instance of the class. (I'd post an answer, but I couldn't get the types working correctly in the time I had to work on it. You'll definitely want to add a constructor accepting the flag, though, at a minimum.)

Comment: You should consider that methods should also be inherited from the child class, and the problem is that I don't have the luxury of such maneuvers because my real case involves dozens of child classes that are dynamically instantiated. Above, I tried to create a similar example to the problem I currently have, but the only problem is that `this['_isManually'] extends true` is not being updated as I change its value

Comment: If you mutate the instance, your types can easily lie to you. That's a very bad idea, regardless of how many object instantiations there are needed to avoid it, IMHO. :-)

Comment: FWIW: Another issue you'll need to fix with the code above is that `TestBaseClass` extends `BaseClass<false>` (always), because `class TestBaseClass extends BaseClass` uses the default value for the type parameter. To make the subclass use the generic, it also has to be generic: `class TestBaseClass<IsManual extends ManualValue> extends BaseClass<IsManual>`. And unfortunately, that's where the pattern you're trying to use falls down. Your `manually` return type is really clever, but it can't fix the type argument on `this`, only on `BaseClass`. But `callRequest` has to have a conditional...

Comment: ...return type based on `IsManual`. So while this may have seemed promising, my advice (for what it's worth!) is to take another tack entirely. Either way, though, good luck! I hope you get a result you're happy with in the end. :-)

Comment: Without direct support for [ms/TS#6223](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6223) there's no way to do this ergonomically.  The closest I can imagine getting is to maintain a "higher-kinded type registry" for `BaseClass` and its subclasses, and then use obnoxious type juggling to simulate it.  As shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N9YQoN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It wasn't the intention to violate copyright, it was simply to make the question clearer by creating a new one. I am thankful to you for the help with the previous question and the current one. I placed the copyright notice at the end of the question, hope you are happy now

Comment: Thanks.  Please see my previous comment and let me know if it fully addresses the question, or if I'm missing something about your intent.

Comment: After analyzing the example you provided, I can see that I'm very close to the solution, but it confused me why you defined the `BaseClassRegistry` interface twice? And another question, would it work the same way if `TestBaseClass` is extended by another class? In other words, a 3-level hierarchy

Comment: I think `ApplyBC` should be updated because it doesn't always recognize the correct classes. btw do all the classes need to be defined here? If yes, it's a bit concerning because I have over 40 classes

Answer (score 0):

There's a **conceptual** problem in what you are trying to do. You're trying to base your return type on the value of a state: Typescript is not aware of the value of the value of the state, so it cannot determine the right type.
Typescript acts at "compile time", while the value of the state (and thus your return value) is determined at "runtime".

There is a way however to put this problem in a way that is conceptually right, which is relying on pure function/objects (which, to make the long story short, returns a value based only on their inputs and NOT using a state if it is not **immutable**).

So a possible alternative to what you want can be the following:

```
export interface IRequest {
    callRequest:(payload?: any) => Promise<Response> | Request
}

export class BaseRequest implements IRequest{
    callRequest(payload?: any): Promise<Response> {
        const request = new Request();
        return request.request();
    }

    manually(isManual: false): BaseRequest
    manually(isManual?: true): ManualRequest
    manually(isManual: boolean = true): BaseRequest | ManualRequest{
        return isManual? new ManualRequest() : this
    }
}

export class ManualRequest implements IRequest {
    callRequest(payload?: any): Request {
        return new Request();
    }
}


const t: Promise<Response> = new BaseRequest().callRequest() // OK
const y: Request = new BaseRequest().manually().callRequest() // OK
```

I share this [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBBCcQQ0MwAUVWDEQC0gADVHBQGNJ3KAALygABEAAkYNAMOB4GRonzFBTBPB3AERcwABS0%20mM9ysygc9wASmCEPFNFgjEEwkekAAjux9DQAN6KEolJxWm1KnWge2Or2gJyofFeJGoDRKgDkxAA8gBZGkAfUe4fuOBpIZ1AG4HY6AL7BL3JeDwN0ejPen2QP1kLwARnTXuz2cUBrI6W232SDCWAElzS6qUWvbVoNBu9aqfklQQmCKGNwAPz5MScPDu7kAPjobEQQkgAB5zYICI1BJA1wAfUDDm2KeuNo0m4QAIQYR4vvahTOhwi7lpHqE9joHQ7fq6E54FOs7zmYS7zrQG5bru%20gHpSx59iWaKUjQzo-jy-SQBI55AVSbo1qhvr%20qWPaoAEmGummxagPWXqIGY7AMIOeBKkIkbMax85ttAR46vOj7PgRqB0UxnAsWxHGCFxkmsXOaBkNagmgHJUkvmJjHcdJnE6fOwJyh4Xi8qgymQKpwmQJpoBnuprGaX%20JakRWIiyTpM44Xh9mARRhbzkMvy1le%20rrIaJh3mpOk2W%207gfqAX4UShJQAZp46TvA06KZBqk2U53ouV4nC4fhfm0cF9bSoeNCoNBsFHvB%206HshvLFXhVlpTqASpaJbpVehoB4PONmtSVHW9V1ElSdA7FdT1ZXBEAA) if you want to play with it

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but it's not sufficient as I have a large number of classes and methods that inherit from each other, and it's not worth defining them all with interfaces and extra classes

Comment: @VildanBina No problem, but if you want to get the result you have to rely on pure functions and find a different way to follow the same concept of what I did. Generics are not meant for that use and won't help you in what you are doing.